# Couldn't find constant subresourceOperations, class App\Entity\Comment

Tags: php, symfony

i have two table comment  and author between them OneToMany relation, i want to display author of comment but it gives me error `[Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant subresourceOperations, class App\Entity\Comment`.
**src\Entity\Comment.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\CommentRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ApiResource(itemOperations={"GET","DELETE",
 *       "PUT"={
 *         "access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') and object.getAuthor() == user"
 *        }
 *      },
 *  collectionOperations={"GET",
 *    "POST"={
 *         "access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')"
 *       },
 *   subresourceOperations={
 *     "api_posts_comments_get_subresource"={
 *        "normalization_context"={
 *            "groups"={"get-comment-with-author"}
 *           }
 *         }
 *        }     
 *       }
 *)
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CommentRepository::class)
 */
```

Comment: The subresourceOperations key should be on the same level as `itemOperations` and `collectionOperations`. In your post, it is inside the `collectionOperations` which is incorrect.

Comment: @JulienB. thx for u answer ,I put itemOperations and collectionOperations and subresourceOperations at the same level but it always gives me the same error, and I don't know what the error is inside collectionOperations

Answer (score 0):

as @julien B said, you have to close "collectionOperations" bracket "}" and put itemOperations and collectionOperations and subresourceOperations at the same level

```
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\CommentRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
* @ApiResource(
*    itemOperations={"GET", "DELETE", 
*      "PUT"={
*            "access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') and object.getAuthor() == user"
*      }
*    },
*    collectionOperations={
*         "GET", 
*         "POST"={
*            "access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')"
*         }
*    },
*    subresourceOperations={
*        "api_posts_comments_get_subresource"={
*            "normalization_context"={
*                "groups"={"get-comment-with-author"}
*            }
*        }
*    }
* )
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CommentRepository::class)
*/
class Comment
```